# Couchbase and R Shiny - Stream data

Tags: r, shiny, couchbase, sql++, nosql

What is the most easy way to stream data from Couchbase into R Shiny- would I be able to do it by using CB's N1QL? Do I need to go for Storm or Spark Streaming or I could use R's "stream" library?

Comment: Check out this blog post] for information about getting Couchbase data into R: https://blog.couchbase.com/incremental-mapreduce-analytics-r/

Answer (score 0):

There's the blog mentioned above, but it's quite old.  I don't know R Shiny (looks interesting though!) but it looks like it relies on dbplyr, which doesn't have direct support for Couchbase's interfaces.  It does, however, have support for ODBC, which [Couchbase also has](https://www.couchbase.com/products/sql-integration).  You may need to 'flatten' out data with the UNNEST clause to get it in the format that R Shiny wants.  You can probably iterate on a query in the Couchbase Web UI, then plug it in there.

Comment: ODBC has always been an option, but not a free one.